# Connecting to API in VB.NET gives 400 error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, curl, webforms, httpwebrequest

This is my first question at Stack...

I have to add an API call to an old VB.NET (Web Forms) page, and Im trying to connect to q web server, but I always get a "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request" error. I can connect thru Postman just fine.

I tried this (among other ways) but it aint working:

```
        Dim httpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://blablabla/access_token"), HttpWebRequest)
        httpWebRequest.Method = "Post"

        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx==")
        Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            Dim Body As String = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=quote"
            streamWriter.Write(Body)
        End Using

        Dim httpResponse = CType(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            TextBox1.Text = result
        End Using
```

And this is the CURL that work just fine on postman (Sorry I had to change the URL)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://blablabla/access_token' \
--header 'Accept: */*' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx==' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=quote'
```

Thank you all. I don't do VB since 2010.

Comment: I've always used `httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic xxxxx")` to add headers, rather than the way you do it. Also you specify `content-type` from your CURL request, but not in VB, and you add `grant_type`, but again not in VB.

Comment: You are right, my apologies, I tried it but it didn't work. I guess filtering the real URL, etc made me post the wrong code. I will edit it now.

Comment: Im new at Stackoverflow... anyone knows how to accept Droopsnoot answer?